# What is the relationship between 'Government and Binding Theory', 'Principles and Parameters', and 'Minimalism?

Tags: syntax, minimalism, principles-and-parameters, government-and-binding

As I understand it, P&P and Minimalism are "programs", which are like different ways of thinking about syntax. G&B is the generative grammar that is based on P&P. (I think that's all correct.) However, it seems like Minimalism is getting rid of some of the G&B rules and structures, so wouldn't this make it a new theory?

Comment: These are different stages of evolution of the same method of inquiry: chronologically P&P > GB > Minimalist Program.

Comment: They are all MIT theories, which means they originated from Chomsky's works and carry his blessing, though it has expired for the earlier ones.